# Testing Workers in worker spec and in Controller Specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a worker that is created after certain action performed in controller action. The worker instantiates another service object. I've written the worker and service object but worker spec is returning zero count. And even I would like to test that the controller action to be performed when certain methods execute. I'm having troubles conceptually understanding what I should be mocking.

This is my controller:

```
   after_action :update_history, only: :create

   def update_history
     HistoryWorker.perform_async(username, email)
   end
```

This is my worker class:

```
   def perform(username, email)
    HistoryEvent.new(params).event //params is one hash which I am passing to service
  end
```

This is how I wrote specs for worker.

```
 let(:worker)        { described_class.new }
 before do
  worker.perform(username, email)
 end
 it "returns a successful status" do
  expect(described_class.jobs.count).to         eq(1)
end
```

described_class.jobs.count is coming 0.

This is controller spec that should perform after create action:

```
   describe "update_history" do
     it "creates jobs for clinic history" do
       expect(HistoryWorker.jobs.count).to         eq(1)
    end
   end
```

In both the cases job count is coming as 0 and in controller specs I am not getting how can I execute this specs after create. Please someone help.

Answer (score 1):

I have done like this and now my worker count is 1:

```
  expect do
    described_class.perform_async(username, email)
  end.to change(described_class.jobs, :size).by(1)
```

Similarly I have done for the controller.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
   expect(HistoryWorker).to receive(:perform_async).with(username, email)
```

you could leave the `.with` out